# ip namespace non-root shell

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ip

I am trying to run `ssh` command to another ip namespace. I can do it right now, but it runs as root. I want to run it as a normal user. I want to know if there is a way to enter a non-root shell in another network namespace.

I know you can use this to enter a root shell in another namespace:
`sudo ip netns exec <namespace> bash`

Alternatively, is there a way to run single commands as a non-root user? I know you can run commands as root with this:
`sudo ip netns exec <namespace> <command>`

Answer (score 0):

The command you are searching for is

```
su --command=' your command ' new_user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be a program that can be installed setuid root so it can do the same things "ip netns exec" does to enter the namespace, but then drops root for the actual exec. Unfortunately I can't find such a thing.

The next best solution is a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [[ "$USER" != "root" || "$SUDO_USER" == "" ]]; then
        echo Call this script from sudo
        exit 1
fi
NS="$1"
shift
ip netns exec "$NS" sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" $*
```

Put that in a file that's writable only by root and somewhere in the path e.g. /usr/local/bin/nsexec

Then to start ssh as your own user in a namespace you can do:

```
sudo nsexec testnamespace ssh
```

It should be safe to put the script name into your sudoers file so you don't get asked for a password. Since the namespace is the first argument you could even make sure only certain namespaces can be used.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  `ssh hostname` use `ssh username@hostname` form. Or you can specify different username by ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host foo*
User foobar
```